# How to maintain the required number of Maven repository versions in Artifactory

Tags: maven, maven-2, artifactory

I have a Maven repository in Artifactory and I have configured it to maintain **two** latest release version for that repository but the repository contains all the **minor** (older) version i.e more than two version in the repository.

Below are the snippet of configuration(image 1) and number of versions in the repository(image 2)
**Image 1:**
[image]

**Image 2**
[image: version in repository]

1. Is the configuration is correct?
2. If my configuration is correct, how can I trigger a action to deleted the un-required version from the repository i.e just to maintain only 2 versions?

Answer (score 3):

You configured it to have two SNAPSHOT versions. SNAPSHOT versions are of the form `3.0.21-SNAPSHOT`. Each new SNAPSHOT version is marked with a timestamp.

The shown versions are release versions. I don't think Artifactory can automatically delete release versions, but you might write a plugin or job that does that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this what I found about the artifactory  automatically deleting release. Reference https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-cleanup-best-practices/ .
FYI : I am using bamboo for deployment/build
If this is not a valid case, can you refer a example like how to use the plugin to execute this task